# How to export content with embedded image as data

Tags: plone, plone-4.x

I would like to export content (richtext-field) with an embedded image. I have created a JSON Webservice that provides Plone content used by mobile Apps (offline).

> > context.text.raw --> gives me the text field content with the embedded image as url. Is there an existing method that will do just that or do I have to filter the image tags, retrieve the image and replace the tag with retrieved data?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: So you want to end up with `<img src="data:...">` if I understand correctly?

Comment: The existing filter for image captions should be a good starting point for identifying images.

Answer (score 0):

no, there's no such method AFAIK...